# Facebook Connecting Accounts (PSID, ASID)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to connect ASID with PSID. My application needs to connect users that comment on a page (message, id, username) with a /me (id, username).
Both are under the same application. I managed to get {user-id}/ids_for_apps to convert the PSID to an ASID, but that only worked after I made the page owned by my business.

I need to get this to work without the whole page ownership thing, because I need it to be automated, because I don't know all the pages/users that will be using the application.

If anyone has any information on this, please help!

Just to clarify:
I have a live streamer oauth my app. Then a viewer oauths my app. I need to identify the viewer oauth with a comment that they leave on the page. When the viewer logs in using my app, it gives them an html control to do things to the stream through chat commands and also on the html controls. Right now, they identify themselves as two different people, because the IDs do not match. I need the html page of the viewer to have an ID that is comparable or the same as an ID from the page comment Both users use my same app. And it's only one page. *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get this to work without the whole page ownership thing

Not possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching#policy:

> The API may only be used by a business to connect the IDs for that business's app or Page to another app or Page owned by and maintained on behalf of the same business. For example, service providers may not use the API to support multiple customers.

---

The purpose of this most likely is to limit how much data any one company can gather about users. It would not be good for privacy, if a large “service provider” could match that data across a multitude of 3rd-party owned pages.

Comment: Just to clarify,

I have a live streamer oauth my app.  Then a viewer oauths my app.   I need to identify the viewer oauth with a comment that they leave on the page.

When the viewer logs in using my app, it gives them an html control to do things to the stream through chat commands and also on the html controls.

Right now, they identify themselves as two different people, because the IDs do not match.  I need the html page of the viewer to have an ID that is comparable or the same as an ID from the page comment

Both users use my same app. And it's only one page. *

Comment: Also this possible with other streaming services such as youtube, twitch, dlive, trovo... I'm really hoping to have a solution

Comment: So you essentially want to do exactly what they say is not allowed - act as a “service provider” middleman. Your requirement can only be fulfilled, when the app and the page are owned by the same business, that is simply the restriction Facebook has placed on this functionality-